# Set-TeamsApp: Error... Failed to execute AMS backend request CreateDocumentRequest

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, microsoft-teams

I have an Azure Devops pipeline that performs a teams app update via powershell.  It has worked fine up until today (typical right?).  Below is the full error we get for all attempts at Set-TeamsApp.  A bit of web searches and on here resulted in nothing useful so I am reaching out to get some insight as to what might be the issue. Thanks in advance.

```
2022-04-11T13:59:55.4529171Z Set-TeamsApp : Error occurred while executing Set-TeamsApp
2022-04-11T13:59:55.4529910Z Code: BadRequest
2022-04-11T13:59:55.4530543Z Message: Failed to execute AMS backend request CreateDocumentRequest. Workload Unknown. Request Url: 
2022-04-11T13:59:55.4531407Z https://us-api.asm.skype.com/v1/objects, Request Method: POST, Response Status Code: BadRequest, Response Headers: 
2022-04-11T13:59:55.4532152Z Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
2022-04-11T13:59:55.4532748Z Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
2022-04-11T13:59:55.4533263Z Date: Mon, 11 Apr 2022 13:59:54 GMT
2022-04-11T13:59:55.4533804Z , Reason Phrase: Bad Request
2022-04-11T13:59:55.4534258Z InnerError:
2022-04-11T13:59:55.4534773Z   RequestId: 36db5e41-86c2-4d8b-96bd-8cd7a4d5824b
2022-04-11T13:59:55.4535335Z   DateTimeStamp: 2022-04-11T13:59:55
2022-04-11T13:59:55.4535856Z HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
```

Comment: We are checking this internally. We will update you

Comment: Much apprecaited

Comment: We have tested set-Teamsapp command. It is working fine at our end. could you please check your command and parameters of command. the error seems to be badrequest. There is some missconfiguration in request. could you please check and try again.

Answer (score 0):

We have tried following set of commands.

1. Connect-Microsoftteams
2. get-Teamsapp (for getting app ID)
3. set-Teamsapp  (Using above app ID- update the app)

It is working fine at our end.

Could you please refer below syntax for set-Teamsapp command

```
Set-TeamsApp
   -Id <String>
   -Path <String>
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/set-teamsapp?view=teams-ps